# how to send the video metadata while uploading video to youtube in ios

Tags: ios, youtube-data-api

I am posting a video on youtube using objective C but the title is not getting updated.
How is the snippet and other meta data send in the POST request.
I am appending this with request body.
{

```
    {
snippet =     {
    categoryId = 1;
    description = "Frodo rocks";
    tags =         (
        Frodo,
        Rocks
    );
    title = Frodo;
};
```

}
}

And getting this as the output from youtube.
{

```
    {
etag = "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/o_39-mkxgb2KbqPNgQNLC4EICnQ\"";
id = "_1vbRs85yu4";
kind = "youtube#video";
snippet =     {
    categoryId = 22;
    channelId = "UCor1dPXm9x-mXmtpPeUviTA";
    channelTitle = "Akanksha Sharma";
    description = "";
    liveBroadcastContent = none;
    localized =         {
        description = "";
        title = unknown;
    };
    publishedAt = "2015-08-11T07:09:46.000Z";
    thumbnails =         {
        default =             {
            height = 90;
            url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_1vbRs85yu4/default.jpg";
            width = 120;
        };
        high =             {
            height = 360;
            url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_1vbRs85yu4/hqdefault.jpg";
            width = 480;
        };
        medium =             {
            height = 180;
            url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_1vbRs85yu4/mqdefault.jpg";
            width = 320;
        };
    };
    title = unknown;
};
```

}

}

Comment: You need to post what you have tried so far..

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ => look at this library, you will get details of integration steps and sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube does not provide any direct APIs for ios video upload.
They have something called as 'Resumable Upload'.
In this you first just upload the video metadata and this request returns you a upload URL on which you can further upload your video.

I built my own library for youtube upload.
https://github.com/NexgearOfficial/NGYoutubeUpload.git